# Writing a bitmap to file in the sdcard

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to compress the bitmap into a jpg in my code. I get a nullpointer exception, Please advice

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Cursor imageCursor=getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,new String[]{MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA},MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME+"=?" ,new String[]{imageTitle},null);
                        imageCursor.moveToFirst();
                        final String imageData=imageCursor.getString(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA));
                        dbConnection connection=new dbConnection(getApplicationContext());
                        SQLiteDatabase db=connection.getWritableDatabase();
                        File imageFile=new File(imageData);
                        File outputFile=new File("mnt/sdcard/Images/hiddenImage.jpg");
                        InputStream is;
                        try 
                        {
                            is = new FileInputStream(imageFile);
                            InputStreamReader inputreader=new InputStreamReader(is);
                            BufferedReader buffReader=new BufferedReader(inputreader);
                            final ByteArrayBuffer buffer=new ByteArrayBuffer(512);
                            int i;
                            while((i=buffReader.read())!=-1)
                            {
                                buffer.append(i);
                            }
                            Bitmap imagefile=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(buffer.toByteArray(), 0, buffer.toByteArray().length);
                            OutputStream os=new FileOutputStream("mnt/sdcard/Images/testing.jpg");
                            imagefile.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
                            os.close();
                        } 
                        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } 
                        catch (IOException e) 
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }).start();
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
07-09 14:57:48.595: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5761): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-9
07-09 14:57:48.595: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5761): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-09 14:57:48.595: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5761):     at com.messageHider.viewImageThumb$1$1.run(viewImageThumb.java:106)
07-09 14:57:48.595: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5761):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

The exception is thrown where I am trying to compress the bitmap:
//::imagefile.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);

Comment: advice #1 - help us to help you - show stacktrace, and tell us where the exception is thrown

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `NullPointerException` in `imagefile.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);`, then `imagefile` must be `null`. This would occur if `BitmapFactory` cannot decode the image.

Also:

- Your file-reading algorithm is very inefficient. Please consider reading more than one byte at a time. Or, better still, use `decodeStream()` rather than `decodeByteArray()` on `BitmapFactory`.
- Make sure you have the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.
- Never hardwire paths, particularly wrong ones, as you are doing here. Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get at the root of external storage, then use the appropriate `File` constructor to assemble a `File` object pointing to whatever file you want within that directory.
- You do nothing to ensure that the `Images/` directory actually exists.